# Which FPGA should I choose? (or should I choose another hardware)

Tags: fpga

You see guys, I've always been interesting in buying one of this development boards, but they were too expensive to me as a student since I had to spent in other proyects, however, I sold some things i don't use and finally made the money to buy one.

So my problem is, I am currently studying electronic engineering, but I've been dedicating a lot of time to programing, reverse engineering stuff and undesrtanding some a little bit complex math cryptographic algorithms (mainly the ones used for hashing) and prime number testing, NP-hard kind of algorithms and some graph path search algorithms, so i wanted to buy an FPGA that was anywhere under $200 that could do the job if i wanted to compute this kind of tasks with him, right now i use my computer for some.

Lets say as example  if i wanted to make an architecture for wpa or md5 brute-forcing, we all know that the numbers go nuts if the password is longer than 8, and eventhough im more interested on understanding deeply how the protocols work and how to implement this ideas, it just would be nice to see it working.

Right now the options I've looked at so far are:

-Cyclone V GX Starter Kit ($179)
which has: Cyclone V GX 5CGXFC5C6F27C7N  Device
https://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=167&No=830

-DE10-Nano Kit ($130)
which has : Cyclone V 5CSEBA6U2317N Device
https://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=167&No=1046

But since im kind of new to FPGA, I mean I've worked with them but used for university projects, with their FPGA's, so i didn't get to know them a lot.
So my final question is, does the FPGA speed depends only on the amount of logif elemnts it has? or, should i care more about that than the other "add-ons" the boards have? because eventhough the second one is cheaper it has lie 30% more Logic elements than the first on, but I don't know if that would mean i would have better performance.

Also, here's the datasheet fot the cyclone V devices:
https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/cyclone-v/cv_51001.pdf

Also thank you for your time on reading this guys, I know it's usually more interesting to solve programming issues and that kind of stuff haha

EDIT: Forgot the "1" on the "$179"

Comment: Oh....sorry guys, didnt know that, is there  any other stack where I should ask questions like these one? (eventhough this one has already beenn solved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boards you've listed has similar speed grade, so won't be any different in raw speed.

GX series include 3Gbps transceivers, and that exact Starter kit has 2.5v levels on HSMC connector. Unless you will be using that connector with some really fast hardware (like 80Msps ADC/DAC, etc), it's unlikely you will benefit from GX. If only due to a bit larger number of hw multipliers available, but that depends on your exact project and needs.

Lots of gpio lines will be lost to hsmc connector. There's boards to fan out hsmc connector into convenient 40-pin gpio connectors, but that will cost another $56. And still you might have difficulties with external hw you will be playing with, since i/o banks on those lines will be using 2.5v levels, while most likely you will have lots of 3.3v devices. It's compatible to a degree and under some conditions, but it's safer to assume there will be issues.

If you will be playing with DIY stuff eventually, then you will need more i/o lines at more convenient voltage of 3.3v. DE10-nano kit looks more promising to me in general case. There's two arm cores that you can use to run higher level logic in linux. It has arduino-compatible connectors, so you can play with existing shields. It's also larger than Starter kit in terms of ALM and on-chip memory, you will need those to instantiate lots of parallel blocks to crunch your numbers.

Sure, if you already have some daughter boards in hsmc format, or planning to have one - you will need some kit with hsmc support.

Comment: thank you!, this was exactly the answer i was looking for, mainly because I didn't know what the "transceivers" were all about, so i think I'm definitely going to buy the nano kit, however i think I'll make another question about how do I know what will my FPGA raw speed be (just being curious)